# ggplot - Fill boxplots with IQR

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I was wondering if there is a direct way to assign the boxplots' fill as their IQR values?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = ??)) # IQR values?
```

Comment: @theArun it's not entirely clear to me why the question you link to is a duplicate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps something like this, using `dplyr` to create the values for `fill = ...`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(mpg_iqr = IQR(mpg)) %>%
ggplot(., aes(factor(cyl), mpg, fill = mpg_iqr)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]